# General Expression Re.sub()

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

I wrote this code:

```
result= re.sub(r"\s\d{3}",r"\0","My phone number is 999-582-9090")
print(result)
```

Got output:

```
My phone number is( )-582-9030
```

why my number is not printed?
Thanks for the help

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @user202729 -- I guess it is obvious; `My phone number is(999)-582-9030`

Comment: @user202729 its is `My phone number is(999)-582-9030`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
\s+(\d{3})(?=-)
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`\s+`** - Represents a whitespace character one or more times.
>
> **`(\d{3})`** - Represents a capturing group capturing first 3 digits.
>
> **`(?=-)`** - Represents a positive lookahead asserting the three digits only before a `-`.

[image: pictorial representation]

You can find the demo in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/bKh910/2)

**Implementation in python:**

```
import re

regex = r"\s+(\d{3})(?=-)"

test_str = "My phone number is 999-582-9090"

subst = " (\\1)"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)
```

You can find the sample run of the above code in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1y75qgp8)